# Laravel Intervention Saving Image show a black image

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using laravel 5.7. I want to scan a directory and resize all files to another direcotry:

```
    $files = scandir('/home/domain/domain.com/storage/products/');
    foreach($files as $mpath) {
        try{
            $file = pathinfo($mpath);
            $t = file_get_contents("/home/domain/domain.com/storage/products/".$file['basename']);
            Log::info($file['basename']) ;
            $mimage_resize = Image::make("/home/domain/domain.com/storage/products/".$file['basename']);
            $mimage_resize->resize(100, 100);
            $mdes = '/home/domain/domain.com/storage/thumb_products/'.$file['basename'];

            $mimage_resize->save($mdes);
        }catch (\Exception $e){

        }

    }
```

But my images with `.png` saved with a black image but `.jpg` workes fine.

Comment: Use encode function (http://image.intervention.io/api/encode) / You can use stream (http://image.intervention.io/api/stream)

Answer (score 0):

```
    $files = scandir('/home/domain/domain.com/storage/products/');

    foreach($files as $file) {
        try{
            $file = new File(resource_path($file));
            $image = Intervention::make($file);
            $imageResource = $image->resize(100, 100, function ($constraint) {
               $constraint->aspectRatio();
               $constraint->upsize();
            });

            $imageBase64 = (string) $imageResource->encode($file->extension(), 90);
            Storage::disk('public')->put($file, $imageBase64);

        }catch (\Exception $e){
           Log::error('error', $e) ;
        }

    }
```